# Opinion Mining - What Database Type?

Tags: orientation, semantics, mining

I am entering a project to make a Opinion Mining (Data Mining -> Web Mining -> Opinion Mining) to get semantic orientation of the words contained. We will use a crawler to get the pages opinion. Now the question is, what type of DataBase should I use (OO, Relational, hierachycal, etc), is best to use in this type of project. 
  I know this is a specific question, Im not expecting everybodies response but at least someone that already did it, that would help.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need something large scale and responsive, you would probably need to go for Google's [BigTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable) or something of that nature. At the prototype level, I am sure you can use traditional relational databases, but at certain point you'd hit the performance wall. See [Brewer's CAP Theorem](http://www.julianbrowne.com/article/viewer/brewers-cap-theorem).

Comment: Yes, it you are looking for such huge systems and data to analyze then certainly you are trying to do something that relational (+ row based) databases are not good at doing.
In fact Facebook also has a column oriented database called Cassandra - http://incubator.apache.org/cassandra/ (which unlike Google's BigTable is open source) for utilizing in such kind of scenarios.

Comment: I doubt such a system will have the hard requirements to warrant a noSQL approach.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience in such kind of scenarios a relational database can serve your purpose pretty well. You need to be extra careful when storing the web content part of it - whether you want to at all use a database to store it or will storing on as simple as a file system can do. BLOBs specially require extra care and they increase your maintenance work.

Also based on the nature of the project, you would certainly be using a lot of already built in components etc. many of which would already support/easy to extend to use a relational DB as a data store.